# can not access id items in a nested objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting the keys returned (0,1..) but can not access the value of _text
This is my data, of type object
the **IdList** is an **object** : **IdList: {Id: Array(6)}**
I'm having the keys but can not access the value of _text

**IdList: {Id: Array(6)}**

```
Id: Array(6)
0: {_text: '34983115'}
1: {_text: '34983114'}
2: {_text: '34983113'}...
```

```
query 
{_declaration: {…}, _doctype: '', eSearchResult: {…}}
eSearchResult:
Count: {_text: '203374'}
IdList:
Id: Array(6)
0: {_text: '34983115'}
1: {_text: '34983114'}
2: {_text: '34983113'}
3: {_text: '34983112'}
4: {_text: '34983111'}
5: {_text: '34983110'}

length: 6
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

I stored the data in an object state named query

```
const [query, setQuery] = useState({});
```

Then tried to access the id in the idlist: the output of this code is index , index._text is undefined

```
 {Object.keys(query).length &&
        Object.keys(query.eSearchResult.IdList.Id).map((keyName, index) => {
          return (
            <div className="card bg-c-blue order-card">
              <div className="card-block" keyy={index}>
                 {index}
                {index._text}
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
```

Comment: Btw, the example object is not easy to decipher.

Comment: tried adding Id,  query.eSearchResult.idList.Id as you suggested but recieved this error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Id')

Comment: The actual field is `IdList` but you use `idList`.

Comment: Is `query.eSearchResult.IdList` undefined? If so, maybe the query is not coming back with the correct data?

Comment: `keyName.Id.map` should probably be just `keyName.map`.

Comment: @kiner_shah yes it's IdList, i wrote wrong, but still having this error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Comment: @evolutionxbox when i console query.eSearchResult.IdList i get an error of undefined

Comment: You will need to do some more debugging to find out why it is undefined. From the example code we cannot tell you why.

Comment: @kiner_shah in this case it returns Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_text}).

Comment: Please provide full code. You may also share a code sandbox link.

Comment: @user be aware that the console only tells you what the object is when you click it in the console. It doesn't mean that it is defined when the code is run.